# UIButton removed from UIStackView

Tags: ios, uibutton, robovm, uistackview

I am attempting to create a row of buttons (four) that will maintain aspect ratio and scale to the bounds of the horizontal `UIStackView` element. This works fine with Images, and every other element that I've tested, however with a `UIButton` I'm running into some very frustrating trouble.

The image does not scale, or stay within the bounds created by the `UIStackView`'s constraints. Instead, the image consumes the entire size of the device application. The strange part is the other objects in the `UIStackView` that are not UI buttons are scaled appropriately, `AND` they are displayed in the correct size, and aspect. They are where they should be based on constraints, however it appears that the `UIButton`is completely detached from the `UIStackView`.

Removing the background image from the `UIButton` results in the button not being visible in the interface, and being removed from the `UIStackView`.  Can anyone point me in the direction of a resolution from this. I guess it would be a good thing to point out that I'm using `RoboVM` so a solution in `Swift` or `Objective-C` would be pretty non-beneficial to me.

Comment: UIStackView rely on the view's intrinsicContentSize() method.  If you override that in the UIButton to return the proper size does that fix it?